# C, compare, int and strings

Tags: c

why == operator compares ints but not strings. I know we are passing references(addresses) in case of strings but I think it is the same in case of int as well. Or does it work any different way? I am confused.

Comment: It is not the same case for `int`s. They are compared by value.

Comment: You will learn why `==` does not work for C strings and then become confused later when you learn that it does work for C++ `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why == operator compares ints but not strings.

In C, objects/constants like `int`, `double`, `char` `123` can be compared with `==`.

Arrays cannot be compared with `==`.

---

In many cases though, the usage of an array is converted to the address of the first element as below.

```
int int_array1[] = { 1,2,3};
int int_array2[] = { 1,2,3};

// This is a pointer compare of address `&int_array1[0]` with address `&int_array2[0]`.
if (int_array1 == int_array2) { ....
```

But not in this case: `sizeof int_array1` is perhaps 3*4 or 12,the size of the array, not the size of "address of the first element".

```
if (sizeof int_array1 == 42) { ....
```

To compare the contents of the 2 arrays

```
// when sizeof int_array1 == sizeof int_array2
if (memcmp(int_array1, int_array2, sizeof int_array1) == 0) { ....
```

---

Likewise with a *string*:

A *string* is an array (or sequence) of characters up to and including the *null character*.

```
char char_array1[] = { '1','2','3',0};
char char_array2[] = { '1','2', 0};

// This is a pointer compare of the address `&char_array1[0]` with `&char_array2[0]`.
if (char_array1 == char_array2) { ....
```

To compare the contents of the 2 strings, perhaps of different lengths,

```
if (strcmp(char_array1, char_array2) == 0) { ....
```

---

> I am confused.

The key difference involves this mantra: "A pointer is not an array - an array is not a pointer".  *Strings* are more like an array with a special content - the terminating *null character*.  `==` compares non-array objects/constants.  Use a function to compare arrays / strings.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are an *array of characters*.

An array always points to the first element like this:

```
char myString[] = "Hello";

printf("address of first element: %p\n", (void*)myString);
```

You *can* compare strings with `str1==str2` but what you are really doing is asking: does `str1` **point** to the same memory location as `str2`?

In some cases this *can* work because constant strings for example are generally stored in read-only memory and reused:

```
const char *myString = "hello";

// may work, but don't rely on it!
if (myString == "hello") {
```

Bottom line: don't do it and use the functions `strcasecmp` and `strncasecmp` to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

int is a single value if you convert it to hexadecimal so it directly compares, however string is an array if characters. so in order to compare strings, you need to compare all the characters one by one, and (==) compares single values(as far as i know).
you need to create a function to do that, or you can use string methods.
[note: I am also a student, not an expert.]